# Find all odd Saturdays and insert them in database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to find all odd Saturdays date and insert them into database. I have written code for all Saturdays but do not know what to do foe only odd Saturdays of a month.

```
    int year = Convert.ToInt32(StartYeartxt.Text);
    int month = 1;

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    for (month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= currentCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, month); i++)
        {
            DateTime d = new DateTime(year, month, i);
            if (d.DayOfWeek == day)
            {
                con = OpenCon.OpenConnection();
                tr = con.BeginTransaction();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Transaction = tr;

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + schemaname + ".[WEEKEND]  ([DATE],[DAYNAME]) VALUES ('" + d + "','" + day + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                tr.Commit();


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What is `day`? Where did you check your Saturday has odd day number? I don't see any check in your code.

Comment: That's because the above code is for all Saturdays. I need to find the odd Saturdays of each month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based upon Tim's answer but finds the week number of the month then selects the odd ones:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

int year = 2016; // 366 days in 2016 because leap year
DateTime yearStart = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
Calendar calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
int daysInYear = (yearStart.AddYears(1) - yearStart).Days; // 366
var oddSaturdays = Enumerable.Range(0, daysInYear)
    .Select(day => yearStart.AddDays(day))
    .Where(date => date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    .Select(myDate => 
         new{date=myDate, 
             weekOfMonth = 
            (calendar.GetWeekOfYear(myDate, 
                                   CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                                   DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            ) - 
            (calendar.GetWeekOfYear(new DateTime(myDate.Year, 
                                                 myDate.Month, 1), 
                                    CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                                    DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            ) + 1}
     )
    .Where(myDate => myDate.weekOfMonth % 2 == 1)
    .Select(date => date.date);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use following LINQ query:

```
int year = 2016; // 366 days in 2016 because leap year
DateTime yearStart = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
int daysInYear = (yearStart.AddYears(1) - yearStart).Days; // 366
var oddSaturdays = Enumerable.Range(0, daysInYear)
    .Select(day => yearStart.AddDays(day))
    .Where(date => date.Day % 2 == 1 && date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);

foreach (DateTime oddSaturday in oddSaturdays)
{ 
    // ...
    string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0}.[WEEKEND] ([DATE],[DAYNAME]) VALUES (@DATE, @DAYNAME)", schemaname);
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = oddSaturday;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DAYNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = oddSaturday.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        int inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Also always use sql parameters and `using` for any object implementing `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't open a connection in each for run. Open it outside of the for loop.

Next always close a connection.

Last to know if a sunday is odd or not u can use the modulo operator or %

a % b = [remaining]

4 % 2 = 0
5 % 2 = 1

So if u do modulo against 2 u will always know if something is odd if the result will be 1. So if u take datetime.day and modulo it against 2 and the result is 1 it's an odd day.

Comment: use modulo where?? I mean first saturday can be an odd date or an even date. How do I get only the first , third and fifthe saturdays in all months of a given year??

Comment: if ((d.DayOfWeek == day) && (d.Day % 2 == 1)

Comment: But it is not necessary that odd Saturday like first or third Saturday of a month have an odd date

Comment: Sr I'm no longer able to follow. Pls describe a bit more, what u need

Comment: I need to find out the dates of first, third and fifth saturday of a month

Comment: Then in ur for loop, just add a counter. Raise it, each time u enter your if and counter check before inserting against, if the counter % 2 is 1. Then u have allways the 1, 3 and 5th saturday